# How to disable autocompletion for quotation marks when writing HTML attributes in PhpStorm?

Tags: html, ide, editor, phpstorm

I'm new to PhpStorm and I'm loving it, but can't find how to disable the autocompletion of double quotation marks when I write HTML tags' attributes. I'm used to not put them and it's very annoying for me.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

In PhpStorm **v7.0** it is not possible.

But it is fixed for **v7.1** -- http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-113332

> Option **"Automatically add quotes for attribute value"** added to IDE
>   "Settings | Editor | Smart Keys".

Either wait for v7.1 to be released .. or try [EAP build](http://eap.jetbrains.com/phpstorm).

Comment: Note that this option does not affect HTML markup contained in strings in JavaScript files (v.7.1.3). In that context, quotes always get auto-inserted, even if this option is disabled.

Answer (score 17):

Note that the setting has in versions > 7.1 been moved to:
Settings -> Editor -> General -> "Smart Keys".

Here you can disable them from being added after attributes equal sign.
You can also disable them so they don't automatically close.

Comment: Thanks. For others using ReactJS and Googling this, it also fixes the annoying behaviour of quotes auto inserted when typing `style=` in JSX code.

Answer (score 0):

As of 2021 this option has been renamed to `Insert pair quote` the path to access it remains `Editor => General => Smart Keys`