# Autocomplete HTML attribute values in JetBrains IDEs

Tags: intellij-idea, phpstorm, webstorm

Is there a way to change autocomplete rule for attribute values in PhpStorm 7.1 (or disable it)?
I mean I want to change autocomplete from

```
<div class=""></div>
```

to

```
<div class=''></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been using PhpStorm since v5, but have not found a way to address this.

However, this behaviour can vary, depending on how you're getting to the quotes.

1. If you're typing `<div class=` and it's automatically filling in the `""` for you, you can remove that by [[unsetting "Automatically add quotes for attribute values"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19998079/3573772)].
2. If you're using tab-completion, like `<div cla[TAB]`, then there doesn't seem to be much you can do, except press backspace after tab. I haven't
3. You can set up your own Live Template `<div class='$END$'></div>` to give you your desired format.

There may be a plugin or two that can change / override PhpStorm's default behaviour, but I haven't looked too much.

Comment: Thank you, first option definitly helps

Answer (score 2):

In addition to already stated **workarounds** by Noah.

It's not possible to choose quote symbol in such case.

Please watch/vote this ticket to get notified on progress: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-459